# I can access my private variables in a category but not framework variables. Why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa

> All instance variables within the scope of the class are also within the scope of the category. That includes all instance variables declared by the class, even ones declared @private.

Therefore, I can do this (and it works):

```
@interface MyControl : UISearchDisplayController
{
    @private
    int privateInteger;
}
@end

@implementation MyControl
@end

@interface MyControl (Private)
@end

@implementation MyControl (Private)

- (void)myMethod
{
    privateInteger = 0;
}

@end
```

But why I cannot do this (I get an undefined symbol link error) :

```
@interface UISearchDisplayController (MyCategory)
@end

@implementation UISearchDisplayController (MyCategory)

- (void)myMethod
{
    _dimmingView = nil;
}

@end
```

_dimmingView is a private variable in UISearchDisplayController.
Is there a build option that allows me to do that, of which I do not know about?

Comment: I am giving you example from categorizing NSCollectionView, method named  displayedItems...check it out

Comment: Categories can't declare variables.